# Is there a way to turn off the blue circle while using MyLocationOverlay in android

Tags: android, maps, mylocationoverlay

I am currently using MyLocationOverlay to display my location. While being on MapView I am forcing the GPS to be turned on as well. However the blue circle around the marker is beyond annoying and I was curious if there's a way to remove it?

Thanks 
Rajat

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to write a custom class to extend `MyLocationOverlay` and `Override` `drawMyLocation()` specifically.  This will allow you to draw whatever you would like, and leave out whatever you'd like to leave out.  This is the example I followed:

[How can I use a custom bitmap for the "you are here" point in a MyLocationOverlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753793/how-can-i-use-a-custom-bitmap-for-the-you-are-here-point-in-a-mylocationoverlay)