# Android : Showing MyLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation as compass

Tags: android, android-mapview, mylocationoverlay

A little Question about the `MyLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation` method in a `MapView`.

In the Original Goggle Maps App there is the Location shown as a Compass, but, if I enable the `MyLocation`-feature in a `MapView` it only shows this blue knob.

How can I replace this blue Knob with the compass-rose from the original Maps-App ??

[image: My App // MapView]

In the Picture above you can see my App. The Location of the User is shown as this little blue knob.

[image: Original Google Maps]

The last picture is a Original from Google Maps. The User Location is shown as a moving Compass arrow.

This arrow is it what I want.

---

Are there any further Informations needed to solve this Problem?

Comment: Have you tried calling `MyLocationOverlay.enableCompass()`?

Comment: @MartinodF The enableCompass-Method shows you a little Compass-Rose in the upper left Corner of the Maps-View, so, this isnt what I need.

Comment: Take a look in this thread: [How can I use a custom bitmap for the “you are here” point in a MyLocationOverlay?][1] it should give you what you need


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753793/how-can-i-use-a-custom-bitmap-for-the-you-are-here-point-in-a-mylocationoverla

Answer (score 0):

I believe the blue dot turns into a blue directional rose when the device can determine your heading, which only happens when you're moving.  I would assume you do not develop in a moving vehicle, yacht, airplane etc. so that would explain your problem.  Unfortunately I can't confirm as I too develop stationary.

Comment: Hi Chris, i put the phone in my car while I driving a little bit around, but, nothing happens with the 'blue dot'. So, I think, I have to overwrite the MyLocationOverlay.class, but no Idea how to handle this :(